# R: obtaining the values of a dataframe based on an ordered vector

Tags: r, database

I would like to obtain the specific values of a dataset. For example:

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="id 
                A187 
                A180 
                C168 
                H897 
                D987 
                C098 
                Q897 
                P987 
                L876")
```

Lets say I have a vector `V = 1 4 5`. I basically want to select th first, and fourth elements of the id such as:

```
df_new <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="id 
                A187 
                H897 
                D987")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `V` as row index and specify the `drop = FALSE` as there is a single column and it is a `data.frame` (to avoid dropping the dimensions as `drop = TRUE` by default)

```
 df[V, , drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
   id
1 A187
4 H897
5 D987
```

#### data

```
V <- c(1, 4, 5)
```